# How to add slider on gutenberg custom block ( on editor not frontend)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am building a custom block (testimonial block)  for Gutenberg editor. Everything is working on the frontend. But on the editor ( backend ) it's not sliding :( How do i implement slick slider on backend editor?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) to load the javascript that initializes slick slider in the editor